# How to Run a Linux Desktop Environment using WSL2 and WSLg without VNC or RDP with Sound, Network and Systemd

Tags: linux, networking, debian, wsl2, user-interface

Kali-Linux has an option to do that by `kex --win -s` or similar commands. But how can I do something similar to other distros. My focus is mainly on Debian Based Distros. Is it possible to do that?

I love to learn programming and development, hence interested in trying out Linux on my Windows PC which is very flexible in this case. Even though, it can be used totally using CLI, I believe having a GUI will help me as a beginner.

I tried installing ubuntu and executing the following commands, hoping WSLg will support this. But it didn't.

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies -y
startxfce4 &
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Virtual Machine instead.  That will accomplish your objectives very well and is easy to set up.  Virtual Box is free for your application.   Sound, Network and Systemd  all included.

This is more suited than WSL for this application and for learning Linux as well.

I have used Kali kex  but my Kali VM works better.

Comment: I heard that VMs are usually slow and takes up more resources. That is why I did not think about that and am trying to use WSL2 and WSLg. And also I don't have a lot storage and ram on my PC.

Comment: I use VMware Workstation and it is very efficient.  The Sound / Network part certainly makes me lean  towards VMs. You need host resources for these kinds of services whatever way you get a machine to run.

Comment: What do you think will be the best minimum specs required to run VMs smoothly on a Windows PC?

Comment: A modern machine normally has enough resources.  8 GB of memory. and Ubuntu runs in 35 GB of disk.  SSD is best and many machines have this.

Comment: Thanks for the information from your expertise. I'll consider trying it. Thanks for your Reply. Highly Appreciated!

Comment: I read your other question. For your machine and as I thought through my answer, try the Desktop versions first.  Once you get some Linux experience you can consider a Server version. Maybe by that time, a somewhat beefier computer may be in order.